# Is there no "easy" way to create a wiki template in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, wiki, template

**Here's what I want to do:** Create 40+ wiki pages that all have the same headings/layout, but will be user-updated to contain unique content on each page. I'd rather not create the "structure" of each page individually step-by-step so I'd like to have a wiki template.

**This is what I'm restricted by:**

1. I can't change the Enterprise Wiki Template because the site is
   also used for other purposes and not all wiki pages on the site will
   use the same template
2. My company will not let us use SharePoint Designer so I don't think I can use the solutions I've found about utilizing content types for wiki pages. *Please tell me if there's another way to allow content types!!*
3. I keep getting an 'unexpected error' when I try to create a new page layout in Design Manager
4. I'd like to stay away from using HTML code as the solution - unless, it's possible to set up the template this way and later allow the users who will update the content to do so directly in the normal wiki body (not modifying HTML)

Can anyone help me figure out a solution?